# how do i fix cors error in next js with stripe?

Tags: reactjs, api, next.js, cors, stripe-payments

I get a cors error saying `Access to XMLHttpRequest at

'https://checkout.stripe.com/c/pay/cs_test_a13NBIQCPQonxjMN9GGvkS9u71VZGdxxJTZblp8mh8owCu72JIhm3vW3X6#fidkdWxOYHwnPyd1blpxYHZxWjA0T09VamtMZmZhaWx3NGZ3fHMxcXxsc0RxY05GY0QwT2JwNWhEazxsbE83dlNEQGJSdEM1bW9Sc0t8UE11S0B0cUZKfEBsdUwyZDFXTUE3UjZqSzFgbG5oNTVVPVIzaWNWcicpJ2N3amhWYHdzYHcnP3F3cGApJ2lkfGpwcVF8dWAnPyd2bGtiaWBabHFgaCcpJ2BrZGdpYFVpZGZgbWppYWB3dic%2FcXdwYHgl' (redirected from 'http://localhost:3000/api/checkout_sessions') from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

I tried using rewrites in the `next.config.js` file but the only problem is that the stripe session id keeps changing.

`

```
module.exports = {

async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/api/checkout_sessions',
        destination: 'what do a put here?',
      },
    ]
  },


}
```

`

So far based off my research using next js rewrites is the only way to solve this cors error but if their is any other way, please tell me.

I have a button that sends a post request to /api/checkout_sessions and thats supposed to forward me to a stripe checkout by giving me a session id. But i get a cors error.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to solve this problem.

1. Don’t use `XMLHttpRequest` or `fetch()` to redirect to Checkout server-side. Instead, use a normal form submit that triggers a server-side function to create a Checkout Session, so that you can use a 303 redirect on the server-side to redirect to the Session URL
2. If you still need to use `XMLHttpRequest` or `fetch()`, you can return the Session’s URL to the client (in a JSON object, for example). From there you can use client-side code navigates to that URL(for example: via [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location#example_1_navigate_to_a_new_page)).